# calculating a percentage from a value C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to output a percentage from a value imputed from a textbox. Here is my code;

```
int firstNumber;
double mydouble1 = 0.15;
int myint1 = (int)mydouble1;

int.TryParse(HouseValue.Text, out firstNumber);

int answer;
answer = (firstNumber) * (myint1);
prem1.Text = answer.ToString();
```

The problem is when I run the app and enter a value to calculate, the answer is 0. I cant seem to get it to display the correct amount for 0.15% of the value.

Comment: Change your `answer` to a `double`.

Comment: You have a `double` then you cast it to an `int`.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change your `answer` from an `int` to a `double`:

```
int firstNumber;
double mydouble1 = 0.15;

if (int.TryParse(HouseValue.Text, out firstNumber))
{
    double answer = firstNumber * mydouble1;
    prem1.Text = answer.ToString(); // you may want to round/format this
}
```

Comment: Casting 0.15 to an int is going to be problematic as well.

Comment: How true. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that casting 0.15 to int makes it 0

```
(int)0.15 == 0
```

The `double` type has primarily been made for scientific calculations. You should use `decimal` when dealing with money, since decimal fractions can often not be translated into binary numbers (used internally to store doubles) without loss of precision.

```
    decimal percentage = 0.15m;
    int houseValue;
    if (Int32.TryParse(HouseValue.Text, out houseValue)) {
        decimal result = Math.Round(percentage * houseValue);
        prem1.Text = result.ToString();
    } else {
        prem1.Text = "Please enter valid house value!";
    }
```

`firstNumber`, `myint1` and `mydouble1` are terrible names. Use speaking names!

Answer (score 0):

Except error handling in converting string to int, use following code:

```
double mydouble1 = 0.15;
double percentage = int.Parse(ouseValue.Text) * mydouble1;
```